# get apple notes from icloud to a pc

Tags: sync, icloud, apple-notes

I use Notes to take notes on an iPad and these are backed up to iCloud. I can see them if I navigate a browser to icloud.com/notes. Can I download these notes somehow? There doesn't seem to be any download functionality whatsoever in the icloud web interface. I installed iCloud for PC, but I don't see Notes in the sync settings. (Do the Notes go in "Mail, Contacts, Calendar, and Tasks", and if so, where does that stuff show up? I don't see them in Outlook.) Surely Apple didn't completely leave out any way of trasferring notes off their services?
[image]

In response to a commend to look in the reminders folder, I don't see any such folder, and looking online I don't see any information that such a folder exists:
[image]

Comment: "When the syncing process is finished, you will find the notes are saved in the "Reminders" folder in your Outlook account, "

Comment: [4 Ways to Download Notes from iCloud on PC or Mac - wikiHow Tech](https://www.wikihow.tech/Download-Notes-from-iCloud-on-PC-or-Mac)

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks, but, for the 1st comment, I don't see a reminders folder (question updated). For the 2nd, the export produces an outlook pst with no data.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Outlook is the only "way" to download notes (other than trying to scrape iCloud Notes). As always, I find it very meaningful that Apple adds a "web" version of iCloud that has missing features like export Notes or collapsing Notes folders...